# Performant way to fetch all rows inside and outside parent record

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I would have the following database structure:
[image: database structure]

And I wanted to get all the records from **Line** that are in a **Page**.

The **PageItems** table contains either a **LineId** value or a **ParagraphId** value for every record.

**Page**

```
Id Title
-----------
1  My page
```

**PageItems**

```
PageId LineId ParagraphId
-------------------------
1      1      NULL
1      2      NULL
1      NULL   1
```

**Paragraph**

```
Id
--
1
```

**ParagraphItems**

```
ParagraphId LineId 
------------------
1           3
1           4
```

**Line**

```
Id Content
------------------
1  Loose line 1
2  Loose line 2
3  Paragraph line 1
4  Paragraph line 2
```

My first thought was using UNION, but since these are big tables that wouldn't work well. So I'm looking for a **single query solution** which I can filter on after selecting the lines.

How would you guys approach this?

Comment: Isn't it possible that you get duplicate lines, if one PageItem links to that Id and another PageItem links to it indirectly via Paragraph? You want those duplicates?

Comment: @TimSchmelter duplicates are no problem, I can filter those out later.

Comment: @GertArnold, all tables have the proper foreign keys in place so the navigational properties are exactly where you'd expect them to be. Yes L2S not EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that it works best to start a LINQ query by the items you want to return in the end and then add the required predicates:

```
var result = context.Lines ...
```

You want lines that belong to a specific `Page` -- let's say you have a `pageId` variable. The lines can belong to a `Page` either directly through `PageItem`s ...

```
var result = context.Lines
                    .Where(l => l.PageItems.Any(pi => pi.PageId == pageId)) ...
```

...or through `ParagraphItem`s, `Paragraph` and `PageItem`s:

```
var result = context.Lines
                    .Where(l => l.PageItems.Any(pi => pi.PageId == pageId)
                             || l.ParagraphItems.Any(pa => pa.Paragraph.PageItems
                                    .Any(pi1 => pi1.PageId == pageId)));
```

This will translate into efficient `Exist` predicates and by the nature of the query no duplicates will be returned.

Comment: This query is really fast. Works great for me. Thanks!!